# How to create a lists of checkBox in a View using asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I have a View and calling my model for checkbox to have a lists  to each other. Each checkbox to a line must have its own and using bootstrap. But they not what i expect them to do. Please assist and attached the mock-up below as what they should be. My logic to do this is as below.

```
// View
```

Dietary requirements

```
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.DietMain.None)<label for="None"> None</label>

     </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
           @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.DietMain.Vegetarian)<label for="Vegetarian">Vegetarian</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

[image]

Comment: What if you put your field into a list and iterate over it on your view?

Comment: As in inside my....?

Comment: A list of your selectable items inside your viewmodel, per example.

Comment: Something like private IENumerable<SelectItemList> GetDietList() {..Logic}@Razor...(@Html.checkBoxFor(model=>model.DietMain......)

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like this:

```
@{
    var checkboxList = new List<string> { "None", "Vegetarian" };
}

@foreach (var checkbox in checkboxList)
{
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                @Html.CheckBox(checkbox, new { Name = $"DietMain_{checkbox}"})
                <label for="@checkbox">@checkbox</label>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

Instead of CheckBoxFor, use CheckBox with setting Name attribute.